# lucene deleteDocuments not working

Tags: java, lucene

> ```
>     /** **************建立索引************************** */
>     // 索引文件目录
> ```

```
//        Directory indexDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File("D:" + File.separator + "testindex"));
        Directory indexDir =  new RAMDirectory();

        System.out.println("当前lucene的版本号是---" + Version.LUCENE_45);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45);

        // 写索引的配置
        IndexWriterConfig writerConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_45, analyzer);

        // 每一次都会进行创建新的索引,第二次删掉原来的创建新的索引
        writerConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig);

        Document document = new Document();

        Field stringField = new TextField("int1", "hello lucky boy", Store.YES);

        Reader reader = new StringReader("hello lucky boy");

        /** ****************创建索引时查看分词的结果************* ****** */
        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("", reader);

        tokenStream.reset();

        CharTermAttribute charTermAttr = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

        System.out.println("tokenStream......" + tokenStream);

        System.out.print("....分词开始....");

        while (tokenStream.incrementToken())
        {

            System.out.print(charTermAttr + "----");

        }
        System.out.print("....分词结束....");

        document.add(stringField);

        indexWriter.addDocument(document);

        indexWriter.close();

        /*******查询term********/
        IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

        TopDocs docs = searcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("int1", "boy")), 10);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;

        System.out.println("......");

        if(null != hits)
        {

            System.out.println("...存在查询的结果..."+hits.length);

            for(ScoreDoc hit : hits)
            {

                System.out.println("命中的结果是......"+hit);

                Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc);

                System.out.println("查询出来的field是......"+doc.get("int1"));

            }

        }


        /** *********更新索引文件document********* */
        System.out.println("...更新索引文件开始...");
        Term term = new Term("int1", "lucky");

        IndexWriterConfig writerConfig2 = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_45, analyzer);

        IndexWriter indexWriter2 = new IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig2);
//        indexWriter2.updateDocument(term, document);

        indexWriter2.deleteDocuments(term);

        indexWriter2.close();
        System.out.println("......" + document);

        System.out.println("...跟新索引文件结束...");
        /** **********跟新索引文件结束**** */


        /**********update/delete之后的操作*********/
        IndexReader indexReaderUpdate = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);

        IndexSearcher searcherUpdate = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

        TopDocs docsUpdate = searcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("int1", "hello")), 10);

        ScoreDoc[] hitsUpdate = docsUpdate.scoreDocs;

        System.out.println("...跟新之后的Search操作...");

        if(null != hitsUpdate)
        {

            System.out.println("...跟新之后存在查询的结果...");

            for(ScoreDoc hit : hitsUpdate)
            {

                System.out.println("命中的结果是......"+hit);

                Document doc = searcher.doc(hit.doc);

                System.out.println("查询出来的field是......"+doc.get("int1"));

            }

        }
```

I  want to delete the docuemnt,however the deleteDocuments method is not working.The document is still the same.Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Which `Document` are you expecting to be deleted?  I don't see any where the `int1` field is set to `lucky`.

Comment: There is only one Docuemnt，Document document = new Document(); Field stringField = new TextField("int1", "hello lucky boy", Store.YES); I want to delete this one.how to do it

Comment: Does it work if you pass `new Term("int1", "hello lucky boy");` to `deleteDocuments` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have opened a new `IndexReader` to perform your second search, which is good, but you pass the old reader into the searcher.  You have also used the old searcher, instead of the new one, when running the search.

So, this:

```
IndexReader indexReaderUpdate = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);

// Use indexReaderUpdate here, instead of indexReader
IndexSearcher searcherUpdate = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

// Use searcherUpdate here, instead of searcher
TopDocs docsUpdate = searcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("int1", "hello")), 10);
```

Should be:

```
IndexReader indexReaderUpdate = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
IndexSearcher searcherUpdate = new IndexSearcher(indexReaderUpdate);
TopDocs docsUpdate = searcherUpdate.search(new TermQuery(new Term("int1", "hello")), 10);
```

Comment: I tested your code with those two changes, and the document is successfully removed, and not returned in the search results.  Did you make *both* of the changes?

Comment: sorry,is is my mistake.however there is another question about  indexWriter2.updateDocument(term, document);.It seems not work.can you give me an example?

Answer (score -1):

```
public final void removeReaderClosedListener(IndexReader.ReaderClosedListener listener)
```